# Having trouble showing existence of pointwise convergent subsequence of a sequence of real-valued pointwise bounded functions on a countable set.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, arzela-ascoli, equicontinuity

I am working on the following exercise from Royden's Real Analysis (Chapter 10, Section 10.1 on the Arzela-Ascoli Theoerem):

> Let $S$ be a countable set, and $\{ f_{n} \}$ a sequence of real-valued functions on $S$ that is pointwise bounded on $S$. Show that there is a subsequence of $\{ f_{n} \}$ that converges pointwise on $S$ to a real-valued function.

So far, this is what I have:

> Suppose $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of real-valued functions defined on a countable set $S$ such that $\forall x \in S$, $|f_{n}(x)|\leq M(x)$.
>
> Since $f_{n}(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall x \in S$, this sequence is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, by Bolzano-Weierstrass, it possesses a convergent subsequence $f_{n_{k}} \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, this just seems too easy, and I never used the fact that $S$ was countable anywhere, so I don't think that this is right.

I'm wondering if I should use the **Arzela-Ascoli Lemma**:

> Let $X$ be a separable metric space and $\{f_{n}\}$ an equicontinuous sequence in $C(X)$ (the linear space of continuous real-valued functions on $X$) that is pointwise bounded. Then a subsequence of $\{f_{n}\}$ converges pointwise on all of $X$ to a real-valued function $f$ on $X$.

But, I'm not told that $S$ is separable, or even a metric space (it's countable. Can I say that it's dense in itself, and thus be able to say that it's separable?). Also, I have to admit I'm not 100% on showing that something is equicontinuous.

Here's the definition of equicontinuity:

> A collection $\mathcal{F}$ of real-valued functions on a metric space $X$ is said to be **equicontinuous** at the point $x \in X$ provided for each $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall f \in \mathcal{F}$ and $x^{\prime} \in X$, if $\rho(x^{\prime},x)<\delta$, then $|f(x^{\prime})-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

But, how can I show that $\{f_{n}\}$ is equicontinuous? Is this where the countability comes into play?

Please help!

Comment: Good thinking here, since you are spotting themes that recur.  One way is to use an idea from the proof of the AA theorem to help here (hint:  diagonal argument).  Another way is to put a discrete metric on your set $S$ that makes   the sequence of  functions equicontinuous and then just claim (quite brashly) that the exercise follows immediately from AA.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, yeah, somebody said something to me about a diagonal argument. The problem is that I am not sure what one would look like in this context (sometimes I have trouble visualizing things like that). How you doing by the way? Haven't seen you on here in a while!

Comment: Hello Kitty, nice to see you too.  Let $S=\{s_1, s_2, s_3,...\}$.  Start, as you did with  a subsequence for $f_n(s_1)$ since that is bounded.  Find a further subsequence (of that first subsequence)  to handle also $f_n(s_2)$ and a further etc.  Now take the diagonal and get a subsequence (of them all) that handles all $s_i$.

Comment: Also someone has answered this previously (this way but with details): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709483/pointwise-converging-subsequence-on-countable-set

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, I saw that, thank you! I didn't realize a diagonal argument was supposed to be an array like that. Glad I looked at it.